# How play video from sd-card cordova phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new to cordova phonegap, i want to browse the video from sdcard and play the video in android. I have tried by hard coding the file uri,

```
   <video id="1"   width="100%"  >
      <source src="file:///storage/0/emulated/videos/video3.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   </video>
```

it is not working.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById("1");
myVideo.load();
```

in your script?